# Does the Nest API provide a way to get historical energy usage?

Tags: nest-api

Ever since I got my Nest all I've wanted is to be able to aggregate my energy usage over a long period of time to look for patterns and mainly appease my curiosity.  Sure there are the monthly usage reports, and the web and device only goes back 10 days.

Does the API expose that data, or would I need to somehow calculate it myself?  I'm not seeing on the API reference anything like 'is_running'.  Or is there a chance a future "Nest Data API" is going to come out?

Comment: I'm thinking about using graphite + a database-backed dashboard to track this data. Here's a great resource: http://dashboarddude.com/blog/2013/01/23/dashboards-for-graphite/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Nest API only provides realtime data, not historical. Nest has an online [community](https://community.nest.com) where they accept product suggestions for future enhancements.

Answer (score 4):

Their API does not give you a way to access the data.
https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api#thermostats

If you've noticed they only store 10 days of data on the thermostat anyway (supposedly). The user agreement for the API also seems to forbid developers from providing software that will aggregate the data over time. I guess for your personal use it might be OK, but you wouldn't be able to distribute it.